# java.util.Set implementation that does not use element.hashCode()

Tags: java, collections, set

Is there a `java.util.Set` implementation that does not call an inserted element's `hashCode()` method?

I have to use some library's class whose `hashCode()` implementation is ill-behaving: when this `hashCode()` method is called, it sends an HTTP request....... therefore, putting an instance of that class into a `HashSet` causes a HTTP request to fire.
I want to reduce interactions with this  `hashCode()` method to a minimum. Therefore, I need a `Set` implementation that does not exploit its contained element's `hashCode()` method.

Comment: [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is the way to go. You need a `Comparator` instead.

Comment: Or extend the dodgy class and override `hashCode()`, may save you more headaches in the future...

Comment: @bmorris591 maybe this class is `final` and OP can't extend it. Another solution (based on your idea) would be creating a wrapper class for this unknown library class and override the `equals` and `hashCode` functions (still, lot of boilerplate code to maintain).

Comment: Ah, good old decorator pattern... Good call. Don't override just cache the outcomes of hashcode.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation of [Object.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method and [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface.

Using [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)< [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) > :

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class NoHashCode implements Comparable< NoHashCode >{

   final int value;

   public NoHashCode( int val ) {
      this.value = val;
   }

   @Override public int hashCode() {
      throw new IllegalStateException( "This method must not be called" );
   }

   @Override
   public int compareTo( NoHashCode o ) {
      return this.value - o.value;
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Set< NoHashCode > set = new TreeSet<>();
      set.add(  new NoHashCode( 1 ));
      set.add(  new NoHashCode( 2 ));
      set.add(  new NoHashCode( 3 ));
      set.add(  new NoHashCode( 1 )); // '1' is already in set
      System.out.println( set.size());// print 3
   }
}
```

Using [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)`< T >(`[comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)`)` :

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class NoHashCode {

   final int value;

   public NoHashCode( int val ) {
      this.value = val;
   }

   @Override public int hashCode() {
      throw new IllegalStateException( "This method must not be called" );
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Set< NoHashCode > set = new TreeSet<>( new Comparator< NoHashCode >(){
         @Override public int compare( NoHashCode left, NoHashCode right ) {
            return left.value - right.value;
         }});
      set.add(  new NoHashCode( 1 ));
      set.add(  new NoHashCode( 2 ));
      set.add(  new NoHashCode( 3 ));
      set.add(  new NoHashCode( 1 )); // '1' is already in set
      System.out.println( set.size());// print 3
   }
}
```